# Core Data updating relationship entity bug with concurrency

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

So i implemented Core Data Concurrency using http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/  i implemented separate private MOC for every object to input data, it works good, i have mainMOC on main thread fetching data using FRC, the only issue that i have faced so far is updating relationship entity.

so if i have Photographer & Photos entities one to many relationship "one photographer can have multiple photos", when user uploads new photo, i update photo entity and photographer "relationship" with the below code... 'note: this is a temp code'

```
+ (Photo *)didUploadNewPhoto:(PhotoClass *)photoObj inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Photo *photo = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photos"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photoID = %@",photoObj.ID];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!matches || error || ([matches count] > 1)) {
        //handle error

    } else if ([matches count]) {
        photo = [matches firstObject];

    } else {

        photo.title = @"";
        photo.timeStamp = @"";
        photo.photographer = [Photographer updatePhotographerClass:photoObj inManagedObjectContext:context];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            //handle Error
        }
    return photo;
}


+ (Photographer *)updatePhotographerClass:(Photo *)photoObj inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Photographer *photographer = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photographer"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PhotographerID= %@",photoObj.PhotographerID];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!matches || error || ([matches count] > 1)) {
        //handle error

    } else if ([matches count]) {

        photographer = [matches firstObject];
        photographer.didUploadPhoto = @YES;

    }
    return photographer;
}
```

The issue i'm facing is that FRC does update photo however, it doesn't update the boolean in Photographer "didUploadPhoto", is there something that I might be missing? if i use this same code using context on main thread, it works great... but if i change it to input data using background thread, it does update Photo but it doesn't update Photographer.

Update:

This is example code of how i call UploadPhoto method using background/private MOC

```
NSManagedObjectContext *tempContext = self.contextStore.newPrivateContext;
[tempContext performBlock:^{
    [Photos didUploadNewPhoto:photoObj inManagedObjectContext:tempContext];
}];
```

and this is how i create privateContext

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)newPrivateContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    [context setUndoManager:nil];

    return context;
}
```

Here is the notification that i use to merge changes...

```
- (void)setupSaveNotification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:nil
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification* note) {
                                                      NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.mainContext;
                                                      if (note.object != moc) {
                                                          [moc performBlock:^(){
                                                              [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
                                                          }];
                                                      }
                                                  }];
}
```

Comment: from your code examples it is not obvious which moc you are really using and what you are passing between contexts. Make sure you are only passing object IDs between managed object contexts!

Comment: Isn't this strange? `!matches || error || ([matches count] > 1)`. if matches is nil or count is greater..

Comment: yea, because i'm only expecting one object...

Comment: @Volker i updated my code, please check

Comment: You are not setting a parent context for your BG context nor do you listen to "did save" notifications. if this is the case, there is no way for the `mainMOC` to receive change notifications.

Comment: I updated my question to show notification that merge changes... i don't know what i'm doing wrong here, it does save Photo obj but it doesn't save updates to the Photographer.